# How can I separate the Stage listener and InputProcessor listener - libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I have two actors:

[image]

and:

[image]

I added firstly the blue actor to the stage and secondly the red actor:

```
blueActor.setPosition(100, 100, Align.center);
redActor.setPosition(100 - 20, 100 + 20, Align.center);

blueActor.addListener(blueListener);
redActor.addListener(redListener);

stage.addActor(blueActor);
stage.addActor(redActor);
```

These actors look like that:

[image]

Their listeners `InputListener` depend on their `ZIndex`s if their `Touchable` are `enable` as shown:

[image]

So far everything works fine if the input processor of the screen is **only** stage:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessors(stage);
```

**BUT** if the input processor of the screen is two processors `Stage` and `InputProcessor`,

```
inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(this, stage);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

the both actors will be touched as shown:

[image]

In this case **HOW** can I separate two listeners of these actors like in the first case ?

Comment: Though actually, I guess I'm making a number of assumptions. Are Red and Blue both still on `Stage`? What do your event handlers currently look like?

Comment: RED on the stage listener but BLUE on inputprocessor interface

Comment: touchdown method of stage retuern true but touchdown and touchup methods of inputprocessor return false

Answer (score 2):

Going by [the source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.java), the constructor of `Multiplexer` adds your arguments in the order you add them.

```
public InputMultiplexer (InputProcessor... processors) {
    for (int i = 0; i < processors.length; i++)
        this.processors.add(processors[i]);
}
```

Then on a `touchDown` event, it runs through them in the same order.

```
public boolean touchDown (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    for (int i = 0, n = processors.size; i < n; i++)
        if (processors.get(i).touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Note that once any returns true, it also returns true and stops the loop.

---

So when you do this:

```
inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(this, stage);
```

it is doing the `touchDown` for `this` first, and then for `stage`. Since Red is on the stage, you'll want to switch the order like this so the Red can handle events first.

```
inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(stage, this);
```

*However, let's say you now have Green, which is also on the Stage but is supposed to be behind* Blue. You'd have to create your own `Multiplexer` class, possibly a child and just override touchDown, and combine/sort the object listeners in each processor using your own method which uses zIndex to decide order*

Comment: yes, but I can't touch BLUE actor anymore which it's in second index of processors !!

Comment: @iOleX even when there is no RED actor in front of it? Make sure RED (*and the scene in general*) is returning *false* to the multiplexer if they did not handle the event.

Comment: is there method like `stage.setTouchable(Touchable.disable);` to make actors only above to inputprocessor

Comment: I found a trick solution. anywhere thanks for answer on my question. I must vote up for you. thanx again :)

Comment: @iOleX No problem, consider answering your own question - it may help others in the future.

Comment: ya I will do it. I'll wait for some time to add some notes and edit my question.

Comment: If you add it as an answer - you can later accept it and get more points for it.

Comment: it may be I didn't fully explained my question perfectly because my answer is very trivial

Comment: this is fully explained my question [here](http://s22.postimg.org/5kqfel2i9/image.png). AND my trivial answer is [here](http://s22.postimg.org/njua3ai9d/ansew.png)